# Kali linux intel wireless drivers

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, intel

I am looking for these drivers online, but I can't find any. Anyone had the same problem?[image]

My wireless adapter is Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260

Comment: Yes, I had this same message when trying to install Debian. What I did was finished the installation, then installed the drivers. I used ethernet for that, as it was the only way of connecting. Wi-Fi then worked. Also, upon installaton, add the output of `lspci -v | grep Network`

Comment: Where did you get drivers from?

Comment: I apt-get them. I had a broadcom card so my driver was WL

Comment: I can't find my anywhere it's a new laptop and I was looking everywhere. I just need those files.

Answer (score 2):

You first need to examine your sources list.

Firmware comes from the non-free repository.

To some extent how your sources list looks depends on which version of Kali you ware using. For the Rolling Release, it looks like this

> deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib

It is important that you have "main contrib non-free"

Then update and upgrade.

The correct command is

> sudo apt install firmware-iwlwifi

Answer (score 1):

You need the `iwlwifi` package, as mentioned [here](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html).

```
sudo apt-get install iwlwifi
```